# jquery-how to get control by id in datagrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datagrid

i have `datagrid` in `asp.net`

one control is Linked to event `onchange="txtChange(this)"`
in `txtChange()` function i want compare it with other control in same line called `txtBox2'
How do I navigate to it with **JQUERY**?

i tried this but it not work

```
function txtChange(textbox) {

     var Var=   $(textbox).prev('input:text[id$="txtBox2"]');

}
```

Comment: try using Client id var Var=   $(textbox).prev('input:text[id$="<%=txtBox2.ClientID%>"]');

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var gvTextboxes = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="TextBox1"]');
var specificTextbox = gvTextBoxes[0];
var specificText = specificTextbox.val();
```

Replace `GridView1`, `TextBox1` with your control names.